# What's you favourite Mac practical joke?

Tags: macos, mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s Your Favorite Harmless Computer Practical Joke?](https://superuser.com/questions/4714/whats-your-favorite-harmless-computer-practical-joke)

Window's guys, seem to have all the [fun](https://superuser.com/questions/4714/whats-your-favorite-harmless-computer-practical-joke).

So what about the Mac, what practical jokes can you play on people who own one?

Comment: community  wiki

Comment: Actually, who sais the other one is for windows guys specifically? I would classify this as a dupe.

Comment: I agree that this is a duplicate. The other question does not explicitly limit the answers to Windows and all these answers will fit the mold.

Comment: Duplicate is deleted. This question should be re-opened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Owning one?

Asking them to right-click? (yes, I know they can now)

Comment: that joke still pisses off the mac fan boys. :)

Comment: Because it's not necessary. Sure, I can right click on my desktop, but many people just haven't figured out that we do not *need* to right click. It's amazing, I know.

Comment: EvilChookie: Come on. As much as I would like to say that the right click is redundant, it just isnt. So many actions are tied to right click, or made simpler by right clicking

Comment: I have to agree with joshhunt, I just couldn't live without my right mouse button even on a mac.

Answer (score 3):

Holding down Shift while initiating window animations such as Exposé makes them happen in slow motion. This lets you do things like:

1. Open a Terminal window. Type in `killall Dock` but don't execute it yet.
2. Switch to another application and initiate a minimize while holding down Shift.
3. Quickly switch back to Terminal and execute the `killall`.

Since the Dock handles the minimization animation, killing it mid-minimize freezes the window in a contorted state. (This is most impressive when using the "Genie" minimization effect, but that's just my opinion.) Bizarrely, however, the window itself is still responsive—try using the keyboard!

Answer (score 2):

[Kernel Panic Screensaver.](http://www.tuaw.com/2007/04/11/mac-os-x-kernel-panic-screensaver-let-the-pranks-begin/)

That is all.

Answer (score 2):

Command-Option-Control-8.  Try it!  It's Fun!

Answer (score 1):

This is platform agnostic, but its still my favorite:

Open a finder window (or any other window) and make sure the application for that window isn't the active application (i.e. the window is in the background). Hide the mouse and the dock and take a screen shot, and set that screen shot as the desktop picture. Now the it looks like you've got a frozen application that you can't find in the force quit list (since the window that is now part of the background image doesn't respond to mouse clicks). The best part is that its completely harmless to the computer as long as the user doesn't go berserk from frustration.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.maclife.com/article/feature/10_os_x_pranks_reign_supreme_over_your_coworkers